# How do I inherit jQuery effects when i introduce a new DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclick, slideshow

I have a slideshow that i replace an unordered list  within the slide show, the images change but any effects are not inherited. this is the script that introduces a new DOM:

```
jQuery("#kwick1").click(function () {
jQuery('#photography').load('/design.html #photography');
});

jQuery("#kwick2").click(function () {
jQuery('#photography').load('/design.html #design');
     });
```

how do i get the jQuery slideshow to inherit this new list of images??
i both these functions and the slide show function in the same file.
I have a

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

that loads the slideshow script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of attaching events to each of elements, you should learn how to use event delegation. That way you can attach single event listener on some container ( or even `document` ) and catch the events as they *bubble up*.

Additionally it will make your code look much cleaner and easier to understand.

- http://lab.distilldesign.com/event-delegation/
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-event-delegation-in-4-minutes/
- http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/

P.S. , if you put your code at the bottom of the HTML ( before `</body>` ) then, when it triggers , it will already be an "onDomReady" event.

Answer (score 1):

You have to let us know what slideshow plugin you are using. Regardless, you probably just need to destroy your old slideshow instance and restart it. Something like:

```
//start slideshow on
var slideshow = $('#slideshow').cycle();
slideshow.start();
$('#button').click( function() {
   //depending on plugin api maybe stop, add and start again
   slideshow.stop();
   slideshow.addImages();
   slideshow.start();
   //or perhaps just destroy old slideshow and restart
   slideshpw = $('#slideshow').cycle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To attach events to newly added elements you should use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [delegate();](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
jQuery('.yourselector').live('click', function(){

//do something on click
});
```

Comment: delegate() is probably better as you can bind it to a specific container, rather than entire document. Also, make sure you have an approriate undelegate() function, to prevent requests from multiplying.

Comment: yes of course, but if i don't have the HTML i can't provide an example with delegate because i wouldn't know what to use so i provided an example only with live()